# C# Deserialisation List Count Zero

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

Having some trouble getting my classes to deserialise correctly.

The other deserialisation classes are working fine and appear to be similar in nature but when the deserialiser runs, I get 0 count for both the ErrorDetail and the String lists.

What have I missed/done wrong?

**XML:**

```
<PlaceOrderResponse
    xmlns="http://blah.co.uk">
    <PlaceOrderResult
        xmlns:a="http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ErrorDetails
            xmlns:b="http://blah.co.uk/Error">
            <b:ErrorDetail>
                <b:Code>1fasd</b:Code>
                <b:Message>Explain</b:Message>
            </b:ErrorDetail>
        </a:ErrorDetails>
        <a:ID i:nil="true"/>
        <a:InformationalMessages
            xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <a:Status>1</a:Status>
        </PlaceOrderResult>
    </PlaceOrderResponse>
```

**C# Classes:**

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PlaceOrderResponse", Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk")]
    public class PlaceOrderResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PlaceOrderResult")]
        public PlaceOrderResult placeOrderResult { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PlaceOrderResult")]
    public class PlaceOrderResult : WebserviceMessage { }

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class WebserviceMessage
    {
        [XmlArray("ErrorDetails")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ErrorDetail", typeof(ErrorDetail))]
        public ErrorDetails errorDetails { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("InformationMessages")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(String))]
        public List<String> InformationMessages { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ErrorDetails")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class ErrorDetails : List<ErrorDetail> { }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ErrorDetail", Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class ErrorDetail
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `XmlArrayItem` will inherit its namespace from its parent.  So you need to explicitly include this:

```
[XmlArrayItem("ErrorDetail", typeof(ErrorDetail), Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error")].
```

Regarding the informational messages, there are no strings to load so it's hard to tell what the XML *should* look like.  It will expect elements of the form `<string>message</string>`

As a tip, the easiest way to debug these issues is to try the reverse - create an object and serialize it to XML. Then compare it to what you are trying to deserlialize and you'll find it quite easy to spot where the differences lie.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I think I had that at one point but something else screwing it up, as I tried to fix,  I just made it a mess, posting here before confused myself further.

Answer (score 1):

Your `XmlRoot` attributes aren't going to do you any good on any class other than your root element of `PlaceOrderResponse`.  You need to add the proper Namespaces to your `XmlArrayItem` attributes instead.

For example:

```
[XmlArray("ErrorDetails")]
[XmlArrayItem("ErrorDetail", typeof(ErrorDetail), Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error")]
public ErrorDetails errorDetails { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through it by hand but I can only assume your class is wrong in some way. Using the class below and your XML I was able to deserialise correctly.

I assume you missed the header off your XML for brevity?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I'll double check and edit the post in case I'm wrong but did you know on .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013 you can go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Class and have Visual Studio write the class for you? That's what I've done.

**Class**

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class PlaceOrderResponse
{

    private PlaceOrderResponsePlaceOrderResult placeOrderResultField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public PlaceOrderResponsePlaceOrderResult PlaceOrderResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.placeOrderResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.placeOrderResultField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk")]
public partial class PlaceOrderResponsePlaceOrderResult
{

    private ErrorDetails errorDetailsField;

    private object idField;

    private object informationalMessagesField;

    private byte statusField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage")]
    public ErrorDetails ErrorDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.errorDetailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.errorDetailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage", IsNullable = true)]
    public object ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage")]
    public object InformationalMessages
    {
        get
        {
            return this.informationalMessagesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.informationalMessagesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage")]
    public byte Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/WebserviceMessage", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ErrorDetails
{

    private ErrorDetail errorDetailField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error")]
    public ErrorDetail ErrorDetail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.errorDetailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.errorDetailField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk/Error", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ErrorDetail
{

    private string codeField;

    private string messageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the missing quote to finish the url string in this line?

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://blah.co.uk)]
```

Comment: Ah thanks, just a spelling mistake, had to hide some of the namespace.